Oauth refresh token lifetime(s)?
How many expiration types for refresh token exist?

One for 24 hours if created from playground without GCP oauth credentials.


One for indefinite time if created based on GCP oauth credentials.
*unless revoked, but originally for indefinite.




Other?


There isn't a time limit enforced by the spec. But, it's a good security practice to keep any token lifetime as short as possible.
TLDR; best practice is to avoid frequent re-authentication is to keep refresh token lifetimes short, but allow getting a new refresh token w/o re-authn.

auth
get access_token and refresh_token
request new tokens with refresh_token
return new access_token and new refresh_token

Optionally, require re-authn after a "total" lifetime which means a new refresh_token isn't returned in step 4
Since it's not specified in the spec, you'll run into different rules with different providers.
If you have control over the authz provider and you want to avoid re-authenticating too often, you can have a new refresh token generated each time you fetch an access token (and also request an a refresh token).
Some implementations will enforce a "total" lifetime, i.e., you can keep getting new refresh tokens until this "total" lifetime is reached. Then, you would need to re-authn in order to start a new "total" lifetime.

If referring specifically to Google OAuth, they vary depending on the type of application. Look at the details of the different types: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#scenarios

Note: Save refresh tokens in secure long-term storage and continue to use them as long as they remain valid. Limits apply to the number of refresh tokens that are issued per client-user combination, and per user across all clients, and these limits are different. If your application requests enough refresh tokens to go over one of the limits, older refresh tokens stop working.
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#:~:text=Note%3A%20Save,tokens%20stop%20working.

In most cases for Google, it looks like there's not a "total" lifetime and refresh tokens don't expire after some duration, but refresh tokens could be revoked if the access token is revoked
